# Trouble with the speed of using in_time_zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.3. Even though currently all of my users are in the same time zone as my server, I thought that in preparation for world domination I'd get rid of all of my `RubyTimeObjIGotOutOfMyDb.getlocal` calls and replace them with `RubyTimeObjIGotOutOfMyDb.in_time_zone(user_timezone)` where the user's timezone is a column in my user's table. What happened is now my page takes maybe 5 or 6 times as long to load. Is this the wrong strategy? Is there a better way I should be preparing for users in different timezones from my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

watching this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1?autoplay=true)

I think you just need to do

controllers/application.rb

```
before_filter :set_user_time_zone

private

def set_user_time_zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if logged_in?
end
```

And all the times will be converted when fetching from db

If times are not in the current timezone, try this in the views (or in console for testing)

```
Time.now.in_time_zone
```

**UPDATE**:
If you are doing that call `in_time_zone(zone)` many times, I think it's fetching the corresponding time difference many times, the way the screencast tells to do, it will fetch only one time and use it in every conversion.